# Create a section separated landing page in react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new with react development and I'm creating a webapp with a public landing page.
I'm using bootstrap and I'm creating a section separated landing page but whe I go to inspect the page I'm a bit confuseb about the page structure.
This is my App.js file

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavMenu />
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/vision" component={Vision} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                    <Route path="*" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div className="container-fluid footer-bg">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-3">
                            <p>Condizioni</p>
                            <ul className="footer-list">
                                <li><a href="/legal">Legal</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-3">
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-3">
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="footer-line"></div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                            <p className="copyright-text">XXXXXXX</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the file Home.js is this

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <section>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-4">
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-8">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section className="section-bg-orange">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <p>
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </section>
            <div className="row">
            </div>
            <div className="row">
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is this separation correct?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Relatively speaking, you have used Section correctly. However, I would advice understanding how to create and import components, in order to make your code look neater, and easy to manage.

Happy Learning :-)

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me some resource?